# MYSQL: Error 1054 - Unknown Column

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

Before we start, I apologize for my MYSQL novice status.  I'm trying to self-teach and struggling a bit with basic the basic structure.

Background on my question: Consider a company that issues bills once a quarter... and roughly two months after the end of the last quarter.  I have a table (Quarter_Identify) that has several columns:

- Quarter_Start  EX: 01-01-2010
- Quarter_End    EX: 03-31-2010
- Quarter_Ident  EX: 1000  <--- iterating number for each quarter (next
  quarter will be 1001)
- Date_Billed    This is the field I'm trying to populate from another table

The other table (Billing_List_1) contains:

- Date_Billed    EX: 05-23-2010
- Lots of other nonsense related to the customers

We take all the orders during the quarter, and bill about 60 days after it ends.  So, in the example above, the 5-23-2010 billing would be related to the Jan - Mar quarter (we bill really late).  I would like to take this date and populate it back as the Date_Billed associated with Quart_Ident "1000".

I'm fairly close and from my research I think I'm running into the issue that my "Where" clause includes a reference to the as-yet not created table "Skyline".  The "skyline" table gets everything together, but is essentially off by a month (I gave up trying to figure out the DateDiff function).  So, I use the bottom piece to offset the result by one and get the right answer... except that it tells me I have an unknown column in my where clause (error 1054) the issue.

```
Select * from
    (select Billing_List_1.date_billed, quarter_identify.quarter_start,
      quarter_identify.quarter_end, quarter_identify.quarter_ident from Billing_List_1
    join quarter_identify
    on Billing_List_1.date_billed > quarter_identify.quarter_start 
      and Billing_list_1.date_billed < quarter_identify.quarter_end)
as SKYLINETABLE;

update quarter_identify A
    set A.date_Billed = SKYLINETABLE.date_Billed 
    where A.quarter_ident = SKYLINETABLE.quarter_ident - 1
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.  Have a great evening all.

---

Solution per TEEZ:  Thanks again for the great help.

```
update quarter_identify A Left join 
    (Select * from
        (select     Billing_List_1.date_billed, 
                    quarter_identify.quarter_start, 
                    quarter_identify.quarter_end, 
                    quarter_identify.quarter_ident from billing_list_1
        join quarter_identify
        on Billing_list_1.date_billed > quarter_identify.quarter_start 
        and Billing_list_1.date_billed < quarter_identify.quarter_end) 
    as T)
    as SKYLINETABLE on 1
    set A.date_billed = SKYLINETABLE.date_billed 
    where A.quarter_ident = SKYLINETABLE.quarter_ident - 1
```

Comment: Seems you explained something extra. We getting confused.

Comment: Cutting to the chase... "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Skyline.quarter_ident' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Any quarter is (if I understand the structure correctly) related with many billings. So, why do you a `Date_Billed` column there?

Comment: There is only one mass billing per quarter.

Comment: @Skyline29: You don't have to add `[SOLVED]` or anything on the title. Once you accept an answer, that is obvious to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are wrong. what is `SKYLINE` table in update query?

You are joining tables in update query but table is not specified. you should use your first query in join with update query.

you need to use join SKYLINETABLE in join with your update query.

Like below:

```
update quarter_identify A left join (Select * from
    (select Billing_List_1.date_billed, quarter_identify.quarter_start,
      quarter_identify.quarter_end, quarter_identify.quarter_ident from Billing_List_1
    join quarter_identify
    on Billing_List_1.date_billed > quarter_identify.quarter_start 
      and Billing_list_1.date_billed < quarter_identify.quarter_end)) as SKYLINETABLE on[... specify on condition....]
    set A.date_Billed = SKYLINETABLE.date_Billed 
    where A.quarter_ident = SKYLINETABLE.quarter_ident - 1
```

Please do required changes

Comment: Good catch Teez, I messed it up while pasting it above.  Corrected the language, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Teez, I'm not sure I understand the "on[... specify on condition....]"... what is this table being Left-Joined to?  The join on line 4 gathered all of the data together

Comment: Teez, you got it.  There was one missing "AS [Whatever]" statement, but you nailed!  Thanks a million.  I'll post the solved code above.  Thanks again.